# C++ Heapsort raise error

Tags: c++, heap, heapsort

This is my full implementation code with some notes. I tried gathering some pieces of code from here and there

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h> 
#include <conio.h>
#include "Header.h"
using namespace std;
void swap(int &x, int &y)
{
int temp = x;
x = y;
y = temp;
}
heap::heap()
{
/*
int x[10] = { 1, 12, 33, 44, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
heapsize = 10;
SetData(x);
*/
}
bool heap::empty()
{
return heapsize == 0;
}
int heap::parent(int index)
{
int x;
if (index % 2 == 0)
{
    x = ((index - 1) / 2);
}
else
{
    x = (index / 2);
}
return x;
}
int heap::left(int index)
    {
int a;
a = 2 * index ;
    return a;
    }
    int heap::right(int index)
    {
int a;
a = 2 * index + 1 ;
return a;
}

void heap::Heapify(int i)
{
int temp, l, r, largest;
l = left(i);
r = right(i);
if ((l <= heapsize) && (A[l] > A[i]))
    largest = l;
else largest = i;
if ((r <= heapsize) && (A[r] > A[largest]))
    largest = r;
if (i != largest)
{
    //swap(A[i], A[largest]);
    temp = A[i];
    A[i] = A[largest];
    A[largest] = temp;
    Heapify(largest);
}
}
void heap::Buildheap()
{
for (int i = heapsize ; i > 0; i--)
    Heapify(i);
}

void heap::insert()
{
int insert;
heapsize = (heapsize + 1);
cout << "insert please:" << endl;
cin >> insert;
int temp = insert;
Buildheap();
cout << "Done!" << endl;
}
void heap::viewheap()
{
Buildheap();

for (int count = 0; count <= heapsize ; count++)
{
    cout << A[count]<<" ";
}
cout << endl << endl;
}
void heap::heapsort()
{
Buildheap();
int temp;
for (int i = 0; i < heapsize; i++)
{
    //temp = A[heapsize -1];
    //A[heapsize -1] = A[0];
    //swap(A[1], A[i]);
    swap(A[1], A[i]);
    heapsize--; 
    Heapify(1);
    /*
    temp = A[heapsize - 1];
    A[heapsize - 1] = A[0];
    heapsize--;
    Buildheap();
    */
}
viewheap();
}
int heap::getmax(int)
{
int temp;
if (empty())
    cout << "Queue is EMPTY!" << endl;
else
{
    Buildheap();
    temp = A[0];
}
return temp;
}
void heap::rmax()
{
if (empty())
    cout << "Queue is EMPTY!" << endl;
else
{
    Buildheap();
    A[0] = A[heapsize];
    heapsize--;

    Heapify(0);
}
}
void heap::SetData(int x[])
{
for (int i = 0; i <= (heapsize); i++)
{
    A[i] = x[i];
}
}
```

and this is my Header :

```
class heap
{
private:
int parent(int);
int left(int);
int right(int);
void Buildheap();

void Heapify(int);
public:
int A[100];
heap();
void insert();
bool empty();
void heapsort();
int getmax(int);
void rmax();
int heapsize;
void viewheap();
void SetData(int[]);
};
```

My code raise error.

Comment: So… what is your problem, actually?

Comment: Please be so polite to read the help->tour. Instead of adding chit-chat and emoticons, describe what your problem is, what your expected output is, what you actually get and any errors it might throw.

Comment: the insert function is not the issue here, if i call it in the main it will work properly, the issue is the heapify OR the build OR the heapsort functions :///

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In implementation of parent instead of

```
 int heap::parent(int index){
    int x;
    if (index % 2 == 0){
      x = ((index - 1) / 2);
    } else {
      x = (index / 2);
    }
    return x;
 }
```

you can simply write

```
  int heap::parent(int index){
    return index / 2;
 }
```

in the method insert, you read new int from console and then call method Build without passing anything, so method Build won't know anything about int 'insert'. 
    When you want to insert new element, you iterate through the whole array and call Heapify for each index. So in your algorithm inserting new element requires nlogn time complexity, which is very huge, inserting an element in heap may be done in logn time. You just need to review algorithm for inserting in heap. 
Here is some demo which describes inserting instructions
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4d/Heapsort-example.gif

also heapsort algorithm

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort

Comment: thanks mate, but yet again the code has an error, lets say i add 5 elements to my array in this order : 1 2 3 6 8 the output is 8 6 1 . . . ???

Answer (score 0):

h::insert() does not seem to insert anything into the data structure.

I can't get a working example.
Would you be so kind and provide a minimal example of the error with output.